# How to add marquee effect on CustomTableViewCell's UILabel?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have customtableview cell. In viewController, I want to add marquee effect in UIlabel placed in custom cell. marquee working perfectly, but I am not able set in custom cell label. **cell.uiprodname.text** is custom cell's label. My code is

```
MarqueeLabel *Label2 = [[MarqueeLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 100, self.view.frame.size.width-20, 20) rate:100.0f andFadeLength:10.0f]; <= here i want to set cell.uiprodname.text instead of cgrect.

Label2.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:15.000];
Label2.text = cell.uiprodname.text;

[self.view addSubview:Label2];
```

I want marquee effect inside each custom cell.

Comment: This may help you ,I tried this blog post [moving 'label text'.](http://blog.stormyprods.com/2009/10/simple-scrolling-uilabel-for-iphone.html)

Comment: Did you try changing the class of the UILabel in the custom cell NIB?

Comment: I tried but not working

Comment: where have you written the above code?

Comment: @Anil I am using cutomcell. I placed this code in cellforRowAtIndexPath method

Comment: marquee effect not working in CustomTableViewCell,table view cell reload when table view cell appear,table view  reuse cell contents when it loading

Answer (score 1):

You need to checkout this code over [github](https://github.com/cbpowell/MarqueeLabel)

You are also required to check the issues coming with MarqueeLabel [here](https://github.com/cbpowell/MarqueeLabel/issues/25)

I personaly did use MarqueeLabel but it causes the app to stuck anytime at any place. So make sure you download the upgradedversion.

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear, follow the following tutorial to create a custom `UITableView`.

[Custom Tableview](http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/)

In that tutorial, when you drag and drop a `UILabel`, change the class in its inspector to the required one (I'm guessing MarqueeLabel). Then drag it into the .h file and continue.